# Return promise if no callback in typescript

Tags: typescript, callback, promise

I want to return a promise if there is no callback in my function. My code is like this:

```
function dropDatabase(callback?: (error: Error, result: boolean) => void): Promise<boolean> {

  if (typeof callback === 'function') return callback(null, true);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));
}

// using
dropDatabase((err, droped) => console.log(droped));

dropDatabase().then(droped => console.log(droped));
```

When I compile I get error like this `Type 'void' is not assignable to Type 'Promise<boolean>'`

How can fix it?

Comment: Don't. Just *always* return a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function signature says it will return a `Promise`. But when you have a callback, you're not returning a `Promise`. Changing the return type to `Promise | void` will fix that.

You can also add multiple type signatures to be clear about exactly when it returns `void` and when it returns a `Promise`. That way you won't have to check what type it actually returned at each usage.

---

Here's the fixed code. I also added the type argument `<boolean>` to `Promise`.

```
function dropDatabase(callback: (error: Error, result: boolean) => void);
function dropDatabase(): Promise<boolean>;

function dropDatabase(callback?: (error: Error, result: boolean) => void): Promise<boolean> | void {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') return callback(null, true);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use overloading:

```
function dropDatabase(callback: (error: Error, result: boolean) => void);
function dropDatabase(): Promise<boolean>;

function dropDatabase(callback?: (error: Error, result: boolean) => void): 
  void | Promise<boolean> {
    if (callback) callback(new Error("error"), true);
    else return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```